# In Qt I want to make my model generation in a separate class for a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

As a C/C# programmer I'm new to Qt and have little experience in C++.
What I want to do is 'making' the model of a QTableView in the class containing my data. In C# I could return a DataSet from a static method in a class containing all my stuff concerning this data, and bind this dataset to my table or list.

```
public class Books
{
   //properties
   ...

   //construtors etc...
   ...

   static DataSet BookData()
   {
       // fill my dataset
       return myDataSet;
   }
}
```

In the main program I then bind my DataSet with the control I wanted to use

Is there a way to do so in Qt / C++ doing the same so that I can write something like:

```
QSqlTableModel* Books::BookData()
{
    // Create an QSqlTableModel
    // Fill it with my data
    return model; // or whatever is possible
}
```

in the main program:

```
...
    ui->tvBooks->setModel(BookData());
...
```

And this with correct garbage cleaning or is this wishful thinking...

tnx

Answer (score 0):

In Qt, this is generally done as follows:

1. Have a model that contains your data.
2. Invoke `setModel` on the view, letting the view display what's in the model.

Qt has two general approaches to models:

1. Use a concrete model and populate it with data. Such models include `QStringListModel`, `QStandardItemModel` and the models that interface databases, such as `QSqlTableModel`.
2. Create a class that derives from one of the base model classes, such as `QAbstractListModel`, `QAbstractTableModel` or `QAbstractItemModel`. Reimplement relevant virtual methods to implement your own model.

In your case, you can, for example:

1. Make the `Books` class have a `QStandardItemModel` as a member, and use it to store the book data. Do not store the data outside of that model. That class should expose the model to outside, and you can then set it on a view. This will be the easier approach, as you don't need to reimplement the model yourself.
2. If you wish to have the flexibility of SQL available to access the data, you can also use an in-memory SQLITE database, and expose it via `QSqlTableModel`, `QSqlQueryModel` or `QSQLRelationalTableModel`. Other than that, the approach would be as above.
3. (your answer) Have a method that returns a newly created static model.
4. Let the `Books` class inherit `QAbstractTableModel`. This requires you to understand the semantics of Qt's models, and is a bit harder.

If you wish to use static models, such as `QSqlQueryModel`, created on the fly each time the database contents change, you can easily leverage `QObject`'s compositeness.

To manage the model's lifetime, it can make itself a view's child automatically, and delete any other instances that are also that view's children:

```
class Books {
  ...
  static QSqlQueryModel * setModelOn(QAbstractItemView * view) {
    Q_ASSERT(view);
    for (auto child : view->findChildren<QSqlQueryModel>())
      delete child;
    auto model = new QSqlQueryModel(view);
    model->setQuery("SELECT name, pagecount FROM books");
    ...
    view->setModel(model);
    return model;
   }
};
```

Comment: tnx, but I don't want to make a class for just the model (I'm satisfied with the standard behavior of the QSqlxxxModel), my class has to encapsulate all data and all methods used to work on the data an one of the possible methods has to deliver the model (on to fill the model declared by the widget).

Comment: @JeanPaulMertens A class that encapsulates all data **is a model**, conceptually speaking. So you **should** make it a model! Your `Books` class should derive from `QAbstractTableModel`. You can use an internal `QSqlTableModel` as needed to access the database, and add whatever convenience methods you wish, and you can forward most calls to the internal model, but you should definitely look into `Books` being a fully fledged model. Otherwise, your views will be static, or will keep resetting and losing selections, scroll position, etc!

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

What I did to solve the case:

```
class Books
{
   static void* GetBookData(QTableView *model)
   {

    model->setTable("books.books");
    model->select();
    ...

   }
};
```

in the library

And:

```
...
QTableView *view = new QTableView;
...

Books::GetBookData(view);
ui->myCombobox->setModel(view);

...

delete view;

...
```

in the main program.

Comment: This certainly works, but has a problem: since you use the model only on one view, and don't use it to manipulate the database, your model is static. If you had a `Books` model that was used *everywhere* to access the books table, you could use it to modify the database, *and* all the views would instantly update as well.

Comment: I've added an example of how you can leverage `QObject`'s compositeness to your advantage by making the model a child of the view. In any case, it seems that your `Books` class should be a model itself. It acts like one, it quacks like one, it *is* a model. Make it so.

Comment: Hey @KubaOber, I use the models only static to fill comboboxes or list to choose from. The class books encapsulates much more than those lists. I can derive from them to manipulate the book-data, create new data etc but then I create a books* bk = new books() an us the methods encapsulated in books to do all kind of stuff. <br/>
So my class is much more than just a model (actually it is not even books :-) )<br/>
P.S. I've found a solution for the garbage collection too.